# Relation and path strategies in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

In Spring Data REST 2.3, the default strategy for choosing repository relations and paths is to pluralize and camel-case the associated entity name. For example, `ServiceInstance` becomes `serviceInstances`.

An identity strategy is in place for entity association and repository search method relations and paths.

My question is whether there is a straightforward-ish way to use an alternative strategy, such as turning `ServiceInstance` into `service-instances` and `findByUsername` into `find-by-username`. I know that Spring HATEOAS has a `RelProvider` API, but I don't see that Spring Data REST makes it easy to inject this. And that's just for rels; I'd like to extend the same treatment to paths.

I'd accept defining a `RelProvider` bean to be straightforward-ish, in the same way we can create a `CurieProvider` bean.

I know I can do these things manually via `@RepositoryRestResource` and `@RestResource` but I'd like to do this systematically.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Data REST 3.1.6 looks like there is still no elegant way to configure this.

The path generation come from the `TypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping` implementation, which does a simple `StringUtils.uncapitalize()` on your domain type. Spring Data REST extends this by implementing a `EvoInflectorTypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping`, which calls the uncapitalize and then apply the plural transformation.

Both `EvoInflectorTypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping` and `TypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping` are instantiated (and not injected) at the `RepositoryCollectionResourceMapping` class, which is further instantiated (and not injected) on a `private final void` at the `RepositoryResourceMappings` class.

Since `RepositoryResourceMappings` is injected in `ProfileController` class constructor, you may be able to extend all those classes and create a new `CustomRepositoryResourceMappings`, and try to bean it so the `ProfileController` will get your implementation, and not the default one.

So, to answer your question about `is there is a straightforward-ish way to use an alternative strategy`, for me there isn't. A straightforward way for me would be to inject or configure my implementation of the `TypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping` class.